# pass part of dataframe name in python def parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, user-defined-functions

How do I pass parts of a dataframe name to a python def?

Ideally, I want the dataframe in the example below named SAMPLEDFTRANSPOSE

```
def transposedf(df, suffix):
   %df_%s , %suffix = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
    
transposedf('SAMPLEDF','TRANSPOSE' )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add more details on why do you need to do that? It seems that there must be a better way. If you can avoid metaprogramming, avoid it.

Comment: The names of internal variables used by `transposedf` aren't the concern of the caller. The function can use whatever variable names it wants.

Comment: I have multiple dataframes I want to transpose